# Add required parameter values for perform GET and POST request in PHP

Tags: php, post, get, slim

I'm trying to figure out how to make more useful and complex my actual [Slim php](https://www.slimframework.com) app (yes, I'm trying to perform something like a very simple APIrest service) in which I have performed some different kinds of request, some as GET request and some as POST request:

**GET request for retrieve all the books object**

```
$app->get('/api/books', function () { 
require_once('db/connector_test.php');

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id");
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if (isset($data)) {
       echo "<pre>";
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
       print json_encode($data);
       echo "</pre>";
       }
});
```

[image: the result data of GET request]

In this case I have already done another GET request for retrieve a specific book object data following the specific `'/api/books/{id}'`url in the GET request and this is the result very simple result:

[image]

**POST request for insert new records**

```
$app->post('/api/books', function ($request) {
    require_once('db/connector_test.php');

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `books` (`title`, `author`, `amazon_url`) VALUES (:stitle,:sauthor,:samazon_url)");
    //$statement->bindParam(':title',':author',':amazon_url', $title, $author, $amazon_url);

    $statement->execute(array(
    "stitle" => $request->getParsedBody()['title'],
    "sauthor" => $request->getParsedBody()['author'],
    "samazon_url" => $request->getParsedBody()['amazon_url']
    ));
```

In this case I have just test it with [Postman client](https://www.getpostman.com/) by adding as Body Parameter the three parameters (title, author, amazon_url) with the values that I want to add in the database performing the POST request.

**What I need to do now? (and this the point of this question)**

I have thought about something that can make these HTTP requests **more secure**, maybe by adding some required parameters in each of these request in order to add a better control to the use of these resources...like an **authkey** or some specific parameters that are mandatory. So the common user that wants to make a GET and a POST request to those resources needs to know which kind of parameter values are needed.

Someone can suggest me how to include this logic both in Slim and in PHP in general? Since I think that if I understand this concept in PHP I can easily understand it also for Slim framework.

Comment: search for middleware in slim

Comment: I have already read it, but I think I didn't catch the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make some sort of authentication over your API
this can be done using middleware in slim  [Middleware in Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html)

Where you can build an access gate around your whole  API or a specific route only 
In this middeleware you can check for Token like JWT token using this
[Slim-JWT](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth)

And also you can check for some paramters Values form the user

Edit to Adding example

**First  you need to create a route to generate JWT Token like**

```
$app->get('/JWTToken',function($req,$res){
$MyJWT=$this->JWT;
    $now = new DateTime();
    $future = new DateTime("now +10 minutes");
   // $server = $request->getServerParams();
    $payload = [
        "iat" => $now->getTimeStamp(),
        "exp" => $future->getTimeStamp(),
        "sub" =>"test for JWT",
    ];
    $secret = "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub";
    $token = $MyJWT->encode($payload, $secret, "HS512");
    $data["status"] = "ok";
    $data["token"] = $token;
    return $res->withStatus(201)
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
});
```

This route will generate a JWT token valid for 10 minutes only

**Second Adding middleware to check Token validation**

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
     "path" => ["/"],
    "passthrough" => ["/JWTToken"],
    "secret" => "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub",
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));
```

This middleware will check for token if its a valid or not 
If true will call your GET or POST route if not will Send unauthorized Error back

You need to update your Composer with theses requirements

```
"firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0",
"tuupola/slim-jwt-auth": "^2.3"
```

**Edit#2**
To send any request you need to send this header

```
Authorization: Bearer  "Token String"
```

Example from postman
[image]

Comment: Can you show me a very simple example of how I can handle this access gate considering my actual code? Maybe require a simple authkey parameter for perform the GET ad the POST request that I have showed above.

Comment: For "path" you mean for example the path set for retrieve some resources like `/api/books`? Now you have set the "/" path, so if I understand well this token validation would affect on every resources path already declared?

Comment: Ya, That is true, This Validation would affect all your routes

Comment: So, for example for the GET method how would be the request considering that we need to pass a token for complete the authentication?

Comment: You will send Authorization header with JWT token data ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146086/discussion-between-ugol-and-ramy-hakam).